# From original text to analyzers to tokenizers to filters to original text back: how in solr?

Tags: filter, solr, reference, tokenize, analyzer

Consider the analysis of the 1st sentence from Wikipedia page of Albert Einstein:

http://localhost:8983/solr/#/trans/analysis?analysis.fieldvalue=Albert%20Einstein%20(14%20March%201879%20%E2%80%93%2018%20April%201955)%20was%20a%20German-born%20theoretical%20physicist%5B5%5D%20who%20developed%20the%20theory%20of%20relativity,%20one%20of%20the%20two%20pillars%20of%20modern%20physics%20(alongside%20quantum%20mechanics)&analysis.fieldtype=text_en&verbose_output=0

and its output:

[image]

Question: Is there any way to get this in some semi-strictured way from solr? Ultimately, I am interesting in referencing the character sequences from the original text to the exact tokens of the last line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web interface in Solr is a thin HTML/Javascript application that works by making calls back into Solr's REST interface to perform any actual work. If you watch the network tab in your browser when you ask the web interface to perform analysis, you can see that it's making a request to:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/corename/analysis/field?wt=json&analysis.showmatch=true&analysis.fieldvalue=foo%20bar&analysis.query=foo%20bar&analysis.fieldtype=text_no
```

And the response is a JSON structure used to build the UI you see:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":108
  },
  "analysis":{
    "field_types":{
      "text_no":{
        "index":[
          "org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer",
          [
            {
              "text":"foo",
              "raw_bytes":"[66 6f 6f]",
              "match":true,
              "start":0,
              "end":3,
              "org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength":1,
              "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
              "position":1,
              "positionHistory":[
                1
              ]
            },
            {
              "text":"bar",
              "raw_bytes":"[62 61 72]",
              "match":true,
              "start":4,
              "end":7,
              "org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionLengthAttribute#positionLength":1,
              "type":"<ALPHANUM>",
              "position":2,
              "positionHistory":[
                2
              ]
            }
          ],
          // .....
        ],
        "query":[
          "org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer",
          [
             // ....
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    "field_names":{

    }
  }
}
```

You can then iterate through the `index` or `query` keys and pick the entries you need (last/first/etc.)

The URL and response format may have changed between Solr versions, but I'm pretty sure it's been stable for the last major versions.

Comment: @mathlindh: informative post. The reason I am posting this is that I would like to highlight all occurrences of a term in the relevant documents. Which means, that from query I get top 10 documents, I reprocess the documents, check the (analyze-chained) query terms that match the (analyze-chained) documents and highlighting the appropriate fields in it. This chain of steps is unavoidable, if I want to offer this functionality, isn't it? it is somewhat tragic that I'd need to do it twice: 1st time on upsert of the doc, and 2nd on the query.

Comment: is there a way to avoid going through a specific core to get the answer (for load balancing purposes?)

Comment: W.r.t. balancing purposes, Erick Erickson from solr mailing list answered this very nicely:

_Within_ a cluster (collection), as long as a request gets to any Solr
node, sub-requests are distributed with an internal software LB. As far as a single collection, you're fine just sending any query to any node. Even if you send a query to a node that hosts no replicas for a collection, Solr
will "do the right thing" and forward it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be also retrieved with the [term-vector-component](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/the-term-vector-component.html). Given you have the component enabled in your `solrconfig.xml` (the file must contain the following lines:)

```
  <searchComponent name="tvComponent" class="solr.TermVectorComponent"/>

  <requestHandler name="/tvrh" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <bool name="tv">true</bool>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>tvComponent</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

and the Schema must have the component correctly configured (the type here matches the german text):

```
<field name="trans" 
  type="text_de" 
  indexed="true" 
  termOffsets="true" 
  stored="true" 
  termPositions="true" 
  termVectors="true" 
  multiValued="true"/>
```

you could retrieve the corresponding values using

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/tvrh?q=trans:tag&rows=1&indent=true&tv.all=true&wt=xml
```

Typical output would be

```
<lst name="zweck">
  <int name="tf">1</int> <- term frequency
  <lst name="positions">
    <int name="position">7</int> <!-- 7th word                       -->
  </lst>
  <lst name="offsets">
    <int name="start">45</int>   <!-- 45th byte in the original text -->
    <int name="end">52</int>     <!-- 52 byte                        -->
  </lst>
  <int name="df">7</int>         <!-- 7 documents have the term      -->
  <double name="tf-idf">0.14285714285714285</double> <-- 1/7         -->
</lst>
```